# GA4, user count

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get unique number of active Users, this code counts the same user couple of times. Withot filter i can just get them with no dimension, but with filer i need to filter dimension.

```
List<Metric> metricslist = new List<Metric>
    {
        new Metric { Name = "activeUsers" },
        new Metric { Name = "sessions" },
        new Metric { Name = "userEngagementDuration" }
    };


    RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest
    {


        Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
        Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "fullPageUrl" }, new Dimension { Name =    "pageTitle" } },
        DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = startDate.ToString(_DATETIMEFORMAT), EndDate = endDate.ToString(_DATETIMEFORMAT) } },
        DimensionFilter = new FilterExpression
        {
            Filter = new Filter
            {
                StringFilter = new StringFilter
                {
                    MatchType = StringFilter.Types.MatchType.Contains,
                    Value = $"/{countrycode}/",
                    CaseSensitive = true
                },
                FieldName = "fullPageUrl"
            }
        }

    };
    request.Metrics.Add(metricslist.Select(metric => new Metric { Name = metric.Name }).ToList());
```

changing the dimensions, filter, removing dimensions.

Comment: What is your question exactly?  Can you give an example or something This doesnt make much sence.

Comment: when I filter users by "countrycode" . I get one user multiple times because when he opens another url he adds it up again, so each domain counts its own active users and that is sometimes the same user. Exc if you open www.something.com/wd/login and www.something.com/wd/info he will count you twice with this filter

Comment: This doesnt sound like a coding issue.

Comment: hmm.. this is example of the reposne i get ( i hided web url) 
"{ ""dimensionValues"": [ { ""value"": ""...login"" }, { ""value"": ""..."" } ], ""metricValues"": [ { ""value"": ""461"" }, { ""value"": ""2505"" }, { ""value"": ""14551"" } ] }"
"{ ""dimensionValues"": [ { ""value"": ""...home"" }, { ""value"": ""..."" } ], ""metricValues"": [ { ""value"": ""226"" }, { ""value"": ""1790"" }, { ""value"": ""28457"" } ] }"
"{ ""dimensionValues"": [ { ""value"": "".../21349/d"" }, { ""value"": ""..." } ], ""metricValues"": [ { ""value"": ""200"" }, { ""value"": ""772"" }, { ""value"": ""20713"" }